# Average of a time derivative

Tags: stochastic-processes

Given a probability distribution P(x,t), we can take the average of a time-dependent quantity x(t) as

\begin{equation}
\overline{x(t)}=\int dx x(t) P(x,t)
\end{equation}

My question is: what if I have to take the average of $\dot{x}(t)=-ax(t)+b\eta(t)$, where $\overline{\eta(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\eta(t)\eta(t')}=\delta(t-t')$?

Is it correct to assume that then:

\begin{equation}
\int dx \dot{x}(t) P(x,t)=\overline{\dot{x}(t)}
\end{equation}

Comment: Looks right to me, why do you think it might be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I think the claim is correct, but the notation can lead to difficulties in computing time derivatives. I would change your first expression for
\begin{equation}
\overline{x(t)}=\int dx  P(x,t) x.
\end{equation}
Indeed, the whole time dependence is encoded in the probability distribution $P(x,t):=P[x(t)=x]$. The variable $x$ inside the integral is a dummy integration variable that runs over all possible positions of the walker, and is not one particular realization or trajectory, which is noted as $x(t)$. Maybe it is more clear using another dummy variable $y$:
\begin{equation}
\overline{x(t)}=\int dy  P(y,t) y=\int dy  P[x(t)=y] y.
\end{equation}

For an Itô stochastic differential equation of the type
$$ \dot{x}(t)=a(x,t)+b(x)\eta (t),$$
we can compute the first moments of the position and velocities as

\begin{equation}
\overline{x(t)}=\int_0^t a(x,s) ds +x(0),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\overline{\dot{x}(t)}=a(x,t),
\end{equation}
respectively.

Therefore, it is true that
\begin{equation}
\overline{\dot{x}(t)}=\frac{d}{dt}\overline{x(t)}=\frac{d}{dt}\int dy P(y,t) y.
\end{equation}

I don't know if the above equality is true for an arbitrary time-dependent diffusion though [$b(x,t)$ instead of $b(x)$].